# map записывает значение, но при извлечении оно отсутствует

Tags: c++, map

Записывается пара значений в `map<HWND, void*>`. Во время отладки записи в `map`, данные присутствуют, и размер `map` имеет 1 единицу, при этом при извлечении данных из `map`, т.е. при последующем вызове запроса данных, размер внезапно становится на 1 единицу меньше, и отдает `nullptr`.

```
#pragma once
#include <winapifamily.h>
#include <map>

class window_base;

typedef std::map<HWND, void*> window_map;

class window_helper
{
    window_helper();

    window_map m_map;

    static window_helper* m_instance_;
public:
    static window_helper instance();

    ~window_helper();

    void release();
    window_base* get_class(HWND hwnd);
    void remove_data(HWND hwnd);
    void add_data(HWND hwnd, window_base* ptr);

};
```

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "window_helper.h"
#include "window_base.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <cassert>

window_helper* window_helper::m_instance_ = nullptr;

window_helper::window_helper()
{
    m_map = window_map();
}

window_helper::~window_helper()
{
    m_map.clear();
}

window_helper window_helper::instance()
{
    if (!m_instance_)
    {
        m_instance_ = new window_helper();
    }

    return *m_instance_;
}

void window_helper::release()
{
    delete m_instance_;
}

window_base * window_helper::get_class(HWND hwnd)
{
    assert(hwnd);
    // запросили
    window_map::iterator data = m_map.find(hwnd);
    return data != m_map.end() ? (window_base*)data->second : nullptr;
}

void window_helper::remove_data(HWND hwnd)
{
    assert(hwnd);
    window_map::iterator data;
    assert((data = m_map.find(hwnd)) == m_map.end());
    m_map.erase(hwnd);
}

void window_helper::add_data(HWND hwnd, window_base * ptr)
{
    assert(!get_class(hwnd));
    assert(hwnd);
    assert(ptr);
    // Добавили
    m_map.insert(std::make_pair(hwnd, (void*)ptr));
}
```

Записали:
[image: Запись]
Пытаемся извлечь:
[image: Извлечение]

Comment: Судя по адресам this, вы пишете в один объект, а читать пытаетесь из другого.

Comment: @Ternvein, >>из другого<< из какого? ИМХО, всё верно, this тут видит сам компилятор, ошибки нет. Другой вопрос, как ТС использует свой класс...

Comment: @test123, видимо ТС использует `window_helper window_helper::instance()`, который возвращает копию, а не ссылку или указатель.
Но вопрос по поводу использования класса, безусловно, актуален.

Comment: @Ternvein: Будь я проклят, но вы правы, запишите как ответ :), копия а не ссылка, как можно было так облажаться

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по выводу отладчка, `this` в двух случаях имеет разные адреса, следовательно доступ осуществляется к двум разным объектам типа `window_helper`.
Ошибка, скорее всего, кроется в неверной реализации функции `window_helper window_helper::instance()`, возвращающей копию объекта, а не ссылку или указатель на существующий `m_instance_`.